# Change how magento calculates "items in cart"

Tags: php, html, magento, shopping-cart

i have a shop where quantities of cards are sold in 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175 and 200. when i add a card, with a quantity of 175 to my basket, the cart total at the top of Magento displays "MY Cart (175 Items)". Obvoulsy it's adding up the quantities, rather than the actual product count.

How would i edit this? What templates is this read from?

Here's a picture to show you what i mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for it in *System > Configuration > Checkout > My Cart Link*.

Comment: You genius! Thank you very much, i would had never found that.